# Given $\sin(\frac{\pi}{12})=\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2\sqrt{2}}.$ express $\sin ( \frac{\pi}{12})$ in the form $\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) (\cos (a\pi)+\cos (b\pi))$

Tags: trigonometry

a and b are rational

I split the fraction into $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$

then take out a factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

then make $\cos (a\pi)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

and $\cos(b\pi)=-\frac{1}{2}$

I get $a=\frac{1}{6}$ and $b=\frac{-1}{3}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly right.  Remember $\cos(-x)\neq -\cos x$

Comment: The edit you made to the post of the OP was almost less readable than the origin post !